# Footer area right side beyond

Tags: html, css

I have two columns layout, the only thing is footer area. After I add a border around it. The right side is beyond the expected area.
http://jsfiddle.net/zhshqzyc/tRqpd/4/

I test it in Firefox. Some css:

```
footer
{
   border-style: solid;
   border-width: 6px;
   margin: 0px;
   clear: both;
   background-color: rgb(178, 178, 178);
   background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(left, #7ac0da 0%, #a4d4e6 100%);
   font-size: .8em;
   text-align: center;
   height: 50px;
   bottom: 0;
   width: 100%;
   padding-top: 20px;
   border-bottom-left-radius: 6px;
   border-bottom-right-radius: 6px;
   border-top-left-radius: 6px;
   border-top-right-radius: 6px;
   color: #336699;
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With default box sizing, border width is calculated in addition to the declared width. So the footer's declared width is 100% of it's containing element, but 6px of border gets added to either side.

Either add `box-sizing: border-box` to make the border become part of the 100% width calculation, or declare your border size as a percentage and subtract it from the `width` (e.g. `width: 98%; border-width: 1%;`).